# Trouble starting Anaconda-Navigator with Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, anaconda

I'm very new to running Linux (and relatively new to using Anaconda as well). My installation seems to have succeeded (i.e. if I do something like `conda list` I can see all of my packages). However, when I try to open anaconda navigator, I'm encountering the following:

```
$ anaconda-navigator 
2021-11-03 20:00:53,693 - WARNING linux_scaling.get_scaling_factor_using_dbus:31
An exception occurred during fetching list of system display settings.

QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-asd21'
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Could not connect to any X display.
```

Can't say that I know what any of this means or how to deal with it. I spent about an hour trying to find solutions online with no success.

Comment: Those error messages make it sound like you're not using a GUI. Are you? What desktop environment (DE) are you running? What version of Ubuntu? And do you know if you're using Wayland?

Comment: Yeah, I just tried it from a TTY (Ctrl+Alt+F3) and got the same last two lines (`qt.qpa.screen:` onwards).

Comment: I'm just running everything from a terminal, no GUI. Ubuntu 20.04. Don't believe I'm using Wayland unless it's something that was installed in the background when setting up Ubuntu...
I essentially just followed the instructions from here: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/
And then tried to verify my installation with this: 
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/verify-install/

Comment: Well there's your problem. Anaconda Navigator is a GUI program. What are you expecting it to do if you're not running a GUI?